# How to delete Instagram posts using API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to delete a specific post on Instagram with JavaScript using API

I tried how to remove a post from the following document.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v13.0/post#deleting

but, I got the following error.

```
Unsupported delete request. Object with ID '{post_id}' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api
```

Comment: You are referring to the normal Graph API documentation there; that is not the same as the Instagram APIs. And the documentation for the latter does not mention any ability to delete posts via API, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instagram does not yet support delete via their API. Please see the [content publishing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media#updating).